# Ionization of hydrogens in hypophosphorous acid

Tags: acid-base, bond, hydrogen

Does anyone know why the hydrogen atoms bonded with phosphorus in $\ce{H3PO2}$ are not ionizable?

I tried looking in high school level books, but they only describe the process, not the real reason. I would appreciate if someone has the answer.

Comment: See, the P-H bond is not all that polar.

Comment: Even nitrogen attached hydrogen atom is very difficult to ionize, and phosphorus has almost the same electronegativity as hydrogen. Nonpolar bonds do not get ionized in aqueous solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, removing another proton from anionic species is not very favorable. For example, the monohydrogen phosphate dianion is not very acidic $(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}\sim 12)$ despite it having an $\ce{OH}$ group.

In the case of $\ce{H3PO2},$ the second and third protons are bonded directly to $\ce{P},$ which is much less electronegative than $\ce{O},$ and consequently these P-H bonds are much less polarized than an $\ce{O-H}$ bond. So these protons are unable to ionize appreciably in aqueous solution.