# Why H3PO2 does not form acid salt?

Tags: acid-base

Why $\ce{H3PO2}$ does not form an acid salt? I didn't understand the language.

Comment: Because it is a monoprotic acid, I guess.

Comment: It is a OK question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionization of hydrogens in hypophosphorous acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124157/ionization-of-hydrogens-in-hypophosphorous-acid)

Comment: Hypochlorous acid has 1 hydrogen attached with oxygen so it is monobasic acid so why can't it make its salt.

Comment: but the statement , hypochlorous acid does not form acid salt is correct. how?